# how use broadcast datagrame socket between 2 android device

Tags: android

i need to sent data with broadcast from a phone to another 
i use this to send data

```
DatagramSocket udp = new DatagramSocket();
                udp.setBroadcast(true);
                String data = miniMe.name + "="
                        + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(),
                        data.getBytes().length,InetAddress
                        .getByName("255.255.255.255"), 7667);
                while (!endBroadCasting) {
                    udp.send(packet);
                    Log.e("host lobby", "boradcast");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
```

and use this for listen data :

```
 castListener = new DatagramSocket(7667);
                    DatagramPacket listenerPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf,
                            300);
                    while (isListening) {
                        Log.e("gamelist", "listening called");
                        castListener.receive(listenerPacket);
                        String temp = new String(listenerPacket.getData())
                                .trim();
                        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(temp,
                                "=");}
```

but i did not get any thing from listener device